# notSupportedError : The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable

Tags: javascript

I want to play audio with js and use equalizer but when I use equalizer I get two errors:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://github.com/rafaelreis-hotmart/Audio-Sample-files/raw/master/sample.mp3.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
>  
>   NotSupportedError: The media
>   resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider
>   object was not suitable.

My code:

```
function initPage(audio) {
        context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        audio.src = "http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"; // the source path
        source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        source.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);
        frequency_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        audio.volume = 1;
        audio.play();
        equlizer = document.getElementById('equlizer');
        let height = $('.music-box').height();
        let width = $('.music-box').width();
        equlizer.height = 400;
        equlizer.width = width;
        centerX = equlizer.width / 2;
        centerY = equlizer.height / 2;
        r = (Math.PI * 2) / bars;
        ctx = equlizer.getContext('2d');
        animationLooper();
    }


    function animationLooper() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, equlizer.width, equlizer.height);
        for (let i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
            let m2, l2, m1, l1;
            analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequency_array);
            frequency_array[i] < 9 ? frequency_array[i] = 9 : frequency_array[i] = frequency_array[i];
            m1 = centerX + (Math.sin(r * i) * (radius + 9));
            m2 = centerY + (Math.cos(r * i) * (radius + 9));
            l1 = centerX + (Math.sin(r * i) * (radius + frequency_array[i]));
            l2 = centerY + (Math.cos(r * i) * (radius + frequency_array[i]));
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            ctx.F = 2;
            let grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(m1, m2, Math.floor(l1), Math.floor(l2));
            grad.addColorStop(0, "#b6b6b6");
            grad.addColorStop(1, "#ffffff");
            ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(m1, m2);
            ctx.lineTo(l1, l2);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLooper);

    }
```